# How to automatically refresh multiple tabs on one datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid, tabs

So I have a an app that has multiple tabs that share one datagrid. I am trying to figure out how to get datagrid to update automatically every hour. Each tab is displaying results of a query from sql server. All the tabs will need to update each hour, as well as, after a new item is added to the database. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF, just bind the DataGrid to a shared DataSource (ObservableCollection).  Update your collection every so often and the DataGrid will automatically update.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" ItemsSource={Binding Path=SharedCollection, Mode=OneWay} .../>
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid2" ItemsSource={Binding Path=SharedCollection, Mode=OneWay} .../>
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid3" ItemsSource={Binding Path=SharedCollection, Mode=OneWay} .../>
```

Code Behind:

```
public class View : Window
{
    public View()
    {
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public ObservableCollection<MyType> SharedCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyType>();
   ...
   ...
   public void UpdateData()
   {
       SharedCollection.Clear();
       var data = GetMyDataFromSQLQuery();
       foreach( var item in data )
       {
           SharedCollection.Add( item );
       }
   }
}
```